# Migrate Sharepoint 2007 to 2010

Tags: development, migration, sql-server

So right now there's a SharePoint 2007 site filled with data. I have to migrate EVERYTHING properly from the SharePoint 2007 site to a new server that has SharePoint 2010 and Windows Server 2008 already installed.

Is there a way to do this without too much trouble?

The SharePoint 2007 site is a production tool and is used quite often and I don't want to destroy anything :x

Answer

Found A detailed Guide

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010setup/thread/8a993fcf-b663-4b67-9ed4-928d26333f37

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with @rjcup3 for the most part, but if your site has no customizations then you do have a chance of being able to upgrade it without requiring a third party tool (DocAve, Quest, etc..).

- Make sure your 2007 site is patched at least to SP2
- run the `stsadm -o pregupgradecheck` command on the server to get a
  feel for how much you will need to change / clean in order to get to 2010
- If that is clean then you will need to copy of your content database
  over from 2007 and attach it to 2010 via the command line (not the UI).  This will kick off the second
  half of the upgrade process and show you the remaining problem areas
- If both the preupgradecheck and the attach are clean then you might
  be able to do a simple detach, copy, attach upgrade

However, 2010 does come with its own pains :

- The single most time consuming issue so far has been dealing with lists
  that have over 5000 items since 2010 introduces list view thresholds
  that throttle views to 5,000 items.  There are a number of strategies
  for handling large lists but there is no 'magic bullet' (aside from
  turning throttling off entirely and gambling with server performance)
- 2010 also introduces the Ribbon which will take some time to train
  your users on
- From an admin perspective, 2010 also does away with the Shared
  Service Provider so you will need to spend some time configuring
  search, user profiles and the like

In the case of my current client, we used a third party tool (DocAve) to migrate content from 2003 to 2007 but then used the content database detach/attach method to go from 2007 to 2010 and that has worked out well for them.

Comment: The fact that it is a VM is more or less irrelevant as long as it has enough resources.  All 16 of our current 2010 servers are VMs.  The detach/attach process only handles content migration, not the whole farm.  You will still need to manually configure the service applications in 2010, that is, Search, User Profiles, Managed Metadata, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Buy a good migration tool.

Migrations are notorious for things going awry. I just finished a rather large 2007 -> 2010 migration for a Fortune 500. Even with a tool there were a number of issues that took multiple test runs to hash out, and then when the problems were down to a manageable level it still took a team of people a week to clean up.

You can do an in-place upgrade or a database detach / reattach, but make sure you test and do thorough validation. We had a client who did their own database detach / reattach and realized a year later that maybe they should have fixed the exceptions from the upgrade at the time they migrated. They're currently rebuilding their environment from the ground up because it would take longer to fix the site than to rebuild.